# No operating system was found while attempting to install 13.04 on a device running Windows 7

Tags: system-installation, 13.04

I was attempting to install Ubuntu 13.04 on my computer that already has Windows 7. However during the installation I got a message saying that no operating system was found on the computer.

The option to delete all of the files and install Ubuntu was the only one. I wasn't given the choice install Ubuntu parallel to Windows 7.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Does your computer have [UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307508/how-to-tell-if-my-laptop-has-uefi)?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I chose the "Do Something Else" option.  I had already cleared out a Partition in Windows using Disk Manager to shrink my main volume.

Now when I choose "do something else" I have free space available.

I made a few partitions:

- Type SWAP greater than or equal to the size of my RAM
- Type EXT4 with a mount point of / which I gave 15GB - Where your programs and OS will go
- Type EXT4 with a mount point of /home which I gave 30GB - Where your personal files will go
- Type EXT4 with a mount point of /boot which I gave 250MB - Boot records

I believe you only NEED the "/" out of those.  Make sure you are selected on "/" when you click "Install Now"

[How large should I make root, home, and swap partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21719/how-large-should-i-make-root-home-and-swap-partitions)

Above is a good answer about the partitions

Why it doesn't have the install along-side option, I don't know.  But I see this most commonly with UEFI set-ups.  Either way, I prefer the other option anyways because you have more control.